# tkinter button command function not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get the input from text box and trying to write them to a file:
I get the error as: retrieve_input is not defined.
Please help me to rectify my code:

coding:

```
import tkinter as tki 
class App(object):

    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root

    # create a Frame for the Text and Scrollbar
        txt_frm = tki.Frame(self.root, width=600, height=400)
        txt_frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        # ensure a consistent GUI size
        txt_frm.grid_propagate(False)   

        self.txt1 = tki.Text(txt_frm, borderwidth=3, relief="sunken", height=4,width=55)
        self.txt1.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
        self.txt1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)

        scrollb1 = tki.Scrollbar(txt_frm, command=self.txt1.yview)
        scrollb1.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nsew')
        self.txt1['yscrollcommand'] = scrollb1.set

        button = tki.Button(self,text=u"Click                                                                     command=retrieve_input) 
        button.grid(column=1,row=0) 
    def retrieve_input():
        input = self.txt1.get("0.0",'END-1c')
        with open('hello.txt','w') as f:
            f.wite(input)  
root = tki.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well with your code how it is now, presumably because you haven't closed the speech marks on the line `button = tki.Button(self,text=u"Click`. It would help, however if you could give us the whole code as well as the full traceback copy-pasted in.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the obvious typos, the problem is this line:

```
button = tki.Button(self,text="Click", command = self.retrieve_input)
```

Notice that the first parameter you pass to tk.Button is self. The first argument must be a widget, but you're giving it self which is not a widget. Perhaps you meant to use txt_form instead?